# Как создать критический процесс в vb .NET?

Tags: vb.net, процесс, visual-basic

Если кто не знает, критический процесс это процесс при завершении которого возникает BSoD. Так вот, меня интересует как создать такой процесс?

Comment: BSOD возникает из-за исключения в ядре виндовс. Где вы прочитали, что такое можно сделать в обычном процессе?

Comment: @Zergatul прочитал я это [здесь](https://www.google.com/amp/s/xakep.ru/2018/02/22/windows-critical-process/%3famp), но перед тем как я это читал я тестил njRat, думаю вы знаете что это, и вот там в билдере есть функция защиты процесса бсодом, когда я включаю эту функцию при завершении моего процесса вылазит бсод, так же есть системный процесс csrss.exe, если его убить тоже будет бсод. Вопрос заключается в том чтобы защитить мой процесс бсодом так же как защищен csrss.exe?

Comment: Да, действительно такое есть. Но там ведь есть описание, как все сделать. В чем проблема перенести код на .net?

Comment: @Zergatul в том что я новичек и не знаю c++. Вобщем можете не отвечать, я на другом сайте нашел код для vb .net и решил свой вопрос.

Comment: @Zergatul еще вопросики по njRat возгикли, там в билде есть фкекция антикил которая делает кнопку закрытия моего процесса неактивной в диспетчере задач, может вы знаете как это в vb .net сделать? Если знаете пишите как ответ, если поможит отмечу решением

Comment: Но если хотите то можно и в коменты, вобщем сами решайте

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Class Form1
    <DllImport("ntdll")> _
    Private Shared Function NtSetInformationProcess(ByVal p As IntPtr, ByVal c As Integer, ByRef i As Integer, ByVal l As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim p As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
        Dim g As Integer = 1
        NtSetInformationProcess(p.Handle, 29, g, 4)
        p.Kill()
    End Sub
End Class
```